# why I cannot see the logs in k8s klog via kubectl logs?

Tags: go, kubernetes, logging, kubectl

I saw some source codes in k8s:

```golang
    // delete immediately, or no graceful deletion supported
    klog.V(6).Infof("going to delete %s from registry: ", name)
```

```golang
    if _, _, err := e.Delete(ctx, accessor.GetName(), deleteValidation, options); err != nil && !apierrors.IsNotFound(err) {
    klog.V(4).Infof("Delete %s in DeleteCollection failed: %v", accessor.GetName(), err)
        errs <- err
        return
    }
```

I think I can check these logs via `kubectl logs`, but I cannot see them, even use `kubectl logs --v 6 <kubeapi server pod> | grep "going to delete"` or `kubectl logs --v 4 <kubeapi server pod> | grep "DeleteCollection"`  I still cannot see the logs that should be output by klog.
How can I check these logs?

Comment: Are you able to see all the logs by removing the "grep" command?

Comment: tried, but still cannnot find these logs which is logged by klog.V(4) or klog.V(6)

Comment: kubectl -v=6 ... Can you check this way?

Comment: I cannot see it via kubectl -v=6, I think this is because the kube api server didn't enable the debug log level(which is v4), I need to add --v 4 flag to kube api server and restart it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
add --v=4 arg to kube api server config file to enable the log verbosity.

File path: `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 192.168.49.2:8443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=192.168.49.2
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --v=4
    .......
```

then kubectl log --v=4

Comment: could be edited to give user better context also remove the sudo cat command as it not required. Just mention the file location